# How to swap Next & Previous buttons in Firefox Quick Find bar

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox 100% of the time on *nix systems. For now I will need to stick with Windows environment and Firefox there has Next and Previous buttons swapped:

[image]

It feels really uncomfortable. Comparing to GTK version:

[image]

Is there some option in about:config or an add-on that can change the order of these buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself. Luckily Firefox is still highly customizable via CSS. So I created a [userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/93039) that does the job. You can change the order of other elements as well.

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

#FindToolbar .findbar-closebutton {
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0 !important;
}

#FindToolbar label {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0 !important;
}

#FindToolbar textbox.findbar-textbox {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1 !important
}

#FindToolbar toolbarbutton.findbar-find-previous,
#FindToolbar toolbarbutton.findbar-find-previous label {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3 !important
}

#FindToolbar toolbarbutton.findbar-find-next,
#FindToolbar toolbarbutton.findbar-find-next label {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4 !important
}

#FindToolbar toolbarbutton.findbar-highlight,
#FindToolbar toolbarbutton.findbar-highlight label {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 5 !important;
}

#FindToolbar checkbox {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 6 !important;
}

.findbar-find-fast.findbar-find-status,
.findbar-find-fast.find-status-icon {
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 7 !important;

}
```

Looks like OSX suffers from same problem, so there is a separate [version](http://userstyles.org/styles/93145) for Mac users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for next and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for previous, much faster and no need to care about button order

Comment: I prefer to use mouse, so hotkeys is not the solution I look for.